# Redux form Submission error has no effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using Redux Form 6.5.0 and used code from here:
http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/submitValidation/

The problem when submitting and throwing a submission error is, that just nothing seems to happen. No update, submit doesn't fail etc. The "throwing" message is being logged though. I think perhaps something is wrong with the promise, but I have no idea on how to apply that.

Unfortunately I'm unable to indent the code, hence I uploaded the code to hastebin...

https://hastebin.com/umegujicop.scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submit handler method must return the Promise which throws the SubmissionError to have an effect.

In my example adding return is enough.

```
handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
   return this.props.dispatch(actions.authUser(formProps.name, formProps.password));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The library needs a `SubmissionError` to be rejected by the promise. I cannot remember if you can just `return` something from inside a `catch()` block and have it be rejected. Maybe try just `return new SubmissionError()`?